# Is there a way to create desktop shortcut via context menu?

Tags: 22.04, gui, appmenu, design

I feel like Ubuntu lacks this quality of life feature, that Windows has. To create shortcuts just by right clicking on icons of applications. I want to be able to do it from anywhere and especially from Applications menu.

Here's how I imagine it:

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnKhc.png)

Moreover, it would be cool for the context menu to have more features.

Is there any extensions or apps to allow you do that?

Comment: Last I heard, gnome **doesn't want** users to have icons on the desktop. From the devs' perspective, it's not a feature they failed to include but a way to mindlessly pollute the UI. If that's still true, they aren't going to give you the choice out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome won't let you by default. XFCE will:

[image]

<strike>As an alternative you could try to install [this addon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) which extends the Gnome's desktop capabilities...</strike> As vanadium pointed out this "addon" is included with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Delete your last line: this "addon" is already included in a default Ubuntu 22.04 install.

Comment: Yeah, I tried XFCE and it's ugly imo and I failed to customize it to look as good as GNOME does

Comment: I understand, it is good that linux has so many choices.